# Error code while trying to use private variables in a function

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I get an error that says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_PRIVATE in
>   E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\SN\AC\ACclass.php
>   on line 6

while trying to run my script. I'm new to classes in PHP and was wondering if someone could point out my error. Here's the code for that part.

```
<?php
class ac
  {
  public function authentication()
    {
    private $plain_username = $_POST['username'];
    private $md5_password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $ac = new ac();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't define class properties (public/private/etc) in functions/methods.  You do it in the body of the class.

```php
class ac
{
    private $plain_username;
    private $md5_password;

    public function authentication()
    {
        $this->plain_username = $_POST['username'];
        $this->md5_password = md5($_POST['password']);
    }
}

//declare a class outside the class
$ac = new ac();
```

If you want to define variables in a function/method, just declare them without the public/private/protected

```php
$plain_username = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: actually declaring class properties inside constructor is a key feature of PHP 8:
https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a `private` variable inside a method, which is not possible.

If you want `ac` to have private variables, you would have to declare them in the class definition:

```
class ac
{

  private $plain_username = $_POST['username'];
  private $md5_password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

and access them in the class's methods using

```
public function authentication()
{

 echo $this->plain_username;
```

By the way, the statement assigning `md5_password` won't work - you can't use functions in class definitions.

You would have to do the `md5` calculation in the class constructor, which would be the cleaner way to do the assignments anyway. In the class, add:

```
function __construct ($plain_username, $password)
 {
   $this->plain_username = $plain_username;
   $this->md5_password = md5 ($password);
 }
```

and then initialize the class:

```
 $ac = new ac($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Public and private are only applied to variables within a class, anywhere else is useless. You cannot request a variable from a function, therefore it can't be defined as public/private/protected. Variables within a function can only have static applied to them (at least that's the only thing I've ever applied to a variable inside a function).